# AngularJS service access variable defined in service

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a Angular utility server and in that I have one method which I am using for searching some values in a JSON as below.

```
angular.module('myAppModule')
.service('myService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
    this.myTestJson = '[{"id":1,"somthing":"somthing"},{"id":2,"somthing":"somthing"}]';

    this.getJsonObj = function(id)
    {
        if(id == null || id == undefined || id == "")
            return null;

        // Units Convert to JSON 
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myTestJson)); // How can I avoid this doing every time ?

        console.log("getJsonObj: jsonObj.length: "+jsonObj.length); //--> Printed invalid number, length of the string 
        for(var index=0;index < jsonObj.length;index++)
        {
            if( id == jsonObj[index].id )
                return jsonObj[index];
        }
        return null;
    };

}]);
```

Problem is I get JSON array length as invalid, and because of that I am not able to loop the array.

How can I access this JSON variable which is defined in the same service.

Comment: why your jason is in string and not just an normal array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.myTestJson = '[{"id":1,"somthing":"somthing"},{"id":2,"somthing":"somthing"}]';
```

So, `myTestJson` is a String containing a JSON payload.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myTestJson));
```

And here, you're serializing this JSON string into JSON, only to reparse it right after. Which doesn't make any sense: you'll end up with the exact same string as the original one. Just like, if you transofmr an integer to a String, and then parse that String into an integer, you'll end up with the original integer.

To parse the original JSON and thus transform it to a JavaScript array, all you need is

```
var array = JSON.parse(this.myTestJson);
```

But even this is completely unnecessary, since you could just use a JavaScript array from the start, instead of parsing a JSON string:

```
var array = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        somthing:"somthing"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        somthing: "somthing"
    }
];
```